# Need assistance with Xcode/database in Mac OS

Tags: database, xcode

I am new to Mac OS and I am unable to understand whether I have any database installed in my system or not. As far as my knowledge is concerned about Mac OS, I am not able to see any database under Applications/Utilities or Applications/Developer.

Can anyone help me choose a basic database I can install in Mac OS? My intent is to learn to connect a DB with the Native app which I am trying to create.

It would be helpful if you could provide me with some useful links for installation and connecting the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Have a start with the Core Data framework.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html

But you could specify what sort of database you want to connect to for a real answer.

Comment: Thanks for your precious time. Actually right now I am working on Proof of concept for iPhone Native App and I don't have any knowledge on Mac OS. Basically I am a .Net developer. I don't know which DB's Mac OS supports and how to install them. I was trying installing "Sequel Pro" but it looks like it require MYSql inside the system. Is it so?

Comment: You'll need to install a MySQL server on your machine as it doesnt come with the OS. But thats trivial as the installer is a one or two click exercise. I dont know anything about connecting to MySQL from ios but there will be plenty of answers here and it cant be too hard as theres about 4500 different MySQL apps in the store. Only slightly fewer than fart apps.

Comment: Hi Warren, Thanks for your input again. One more thing is that I am working on Proof of concept only. In actual scenario I will be calling Web Services from the app. It's just we wants to check how to start working on Xcode as no one know about it. I just now installed MySql 5.5.8 in my system which is having Mac OS 10.5.3 and I started the server from system preferences but the problem I am facing now is how to open mysql to start working. :P It's very strange to me as I am used to working on windows not on Mac OS. :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you could have a look at [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info) to get a quick setup.

I know it's not perfect, but it contains stuff for administrating, as well as a default install of a MySQL DB.

On the other hand, if you feel adventurous (not a big deal):

- You can try [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) as a standalone package.
- My advice would be to use [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) as well; it's a very good GUI tool for MySQL administration.

However, you should take some SQL training beforehand. It'll give you a clear view of what can and can not be done with it, and help you avoid some common mistakes.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql) is a good start for that to give you an idea.